# Why does window have a self-reference window property

Tags: javascript, object, window

In browsers, the global `window` object has a `window` property, which is nothing but a slef-reference to the `window` object itself.

I can't see the utility of such a property?

The problem is that with this self-reference we can have a nested access level which will give always the same reference, why does it allow us to write `window.window.window` with an infinite number of `window`?

And if we write:

```
window.window.window.window.window == window
```

It prints:

> true

**Demo:**

```js
console.log(window.window.window.window.window == window);
```

Does anyone know the purpose of having such a property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The point of having the window property refer to the object itself, was likely to make it easy to refer to the global object. Otherwise, you'd have to do a manual var window = this; assignment at the top of your script.
>   <sub>[**MDN `window`** reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window)</sub>